# Looking for a Chazon Ish about developement of Minhagim

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, chazon-ish

It has stuck in my head for a while now - roughly quoted as saying that one shouldn't mock minhagim that have developed in klal yisroel even if the origin seems dubious - as Hashem wouldn't allow pointless or harmful minhagim to fester among his nation just trying to follow halacha and mesorah - so any minhag is by definition with hashem's haskamah.

Something along those lines.  90% sure it was chazon ish, couldn't find in his igros though...

Comment: Tzvi, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and  thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you get help finding the source you're looking for. You may also be interested in looking around at some of our other [tag:chazon-ish] or [tag:minhag] questions. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: Curious then what happens to the well-established halachic concept of *minhag ta'us* (erroneous custom)...

Comment: Not sure how that opinion jives with this.."Despite a longstanding tradition to perform kaparot, Ramban (cited in Orchot Chaim, Hilchot Erev Yom HaKippurim no.1) rules that kaparot is a violation of darchei ha'Emori, the prohibition of following the ways of idol worshippers (Vayikra 18:3). Rashba, Teshuvot HaRashba 1:395, notes that he did not allow kaparot in his community, ostensibly for the same reason as Ramban. Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 605:1, codifies the opinion of Rashba (he states that one should avoid this practice but does not mention the prohibition of darchei ha'Emori)."

Comment: Would you be willing to accept answers from sources other than the Hazon Ish?

Answer (score 2):

השו"ת קטנות (סי' ט') כיון דבודאי ה' לא יביא תקלה לעמו להמשך ולנהוג כן, ואם נמשך כן המנהג הרי שזה מוכח שכן הלכה.‏

Comment: Please translate your answers for the benefits of non-Hebrew speakers